# Pandas applying regex to replace values with exception

Tags: regex, python-2.7

How can I re-write this code line to make exception for "," and ".".

```
df['A1'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `\D` into its equivalent `[^\d]` and add these chars to the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
df['A1'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'[^\d,.]',value=r'')
                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

The `\D` matches any non-digits (so, `.` and `,` are matched) while `[^\d,.]` matches any char that is not a digit, `.` and `,`.